# How to convert getStartMillis to normal time format in Selenium (Posting results to Splunk from Selenium code through jenkins)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, splunk

I am using this ITestResult interface and making use of methods within this. But I am running into a problem where StartTime and EndTime are showing up in a weird format like EndTime: 1574335356061 and    **StartTime: 1574334748190** in my splunk report. Same is the case with Total time   **TotalTime: 607871**.

Is there a way I can get Start time, End time and totak time in a normal format.

Below is the code I have written.

```
public static void postLabTestResult(ITestResult test) {
        String testResult = test.getStatus()==1 ? "PASS" : "FAIL" ;
        String testFailReason = test.getThrowable() != null ? test.getThrowable().toString() : "NotDefined";
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(new Date());
        StringBuilder Entry = new StringBuilder();
        DesktopOSType desktopOS = TestRun.getOS();
        Entry.append("{\"DateTime\": " + "\"" + dateTime + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"StartTime\": " + "\"" + test.getStartMillis() + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"EndTime\": " + "\"" + test.getEndMillis() + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"TotalTime\": " + "\"" + (test.getEndMillis() - test.getStartMillis()) + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"LabTestFailReason\": " + "\"" + testFailReason.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "") + "\"}]}");

        //post to splunk
        Logger.logMessage("LabTestData posted:  "+ SplunkManager.postEvent(ConfigProps.SPLUNK_INDEX, Entry.toString()));
    }
```

The splunk report shows something like this

```
   EndTime: 1574335356061
   LabTestFailReason: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
   LabTestName: verifyLoginTest
   LabTestResult: FAIL
   StartTime: 1574334748190
   TotalTime: 607871
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, when u call test.getStartMillis() u r getting Epoch time format 
https://www.epochconverter.com . You need to convert it to "human" date format.

Something like:

```
  long yourEpochTime = 1574335356061;
Date d = new Date(yourEpochTime * 1000);
```

or

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks but how about the time difference that I need to calculate based on Start time and End time to get the total time that it took for my script to run?

`long startTime = test.getStartMillis();
        Date dStartTime = new Date(startTime * 1000);
        long endTime = test.getStartMillis();
        Date dEndTime = new Date(endTime * 1000);
        
        Entry.append("\"StartTime\": " + "\"" + dStartTime + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"EndTime\": " + "\"" + dEndTime + "\", ");
`

Comment: To get the time difference I went with below code


`long startTime = test.getStartMillis();
        Date dStartTime = new Date(startTime * 1000);
        long endTime = test.getStartMillis();
        Date dEndTime = new Date(endTime * 1000);
        long difference = dStartTime.getTime() - dEndTime.getTime();
        Entry.append("\"StartTime\": " + "\"" + dStartTime + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"EndTime\": " + "\"" + dEndTime + "\", ");
        Entry.append("\"TotalTime\": " + "\"" + difference + "\", "); `

Comment: `DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date.format(date));`  How will this help me getting the start and end time based on my script.

Comment: Its just an example, so u were able to get time difference?

Comment: `EndTime: Sun Sep 04 02:25:00 EST 51859
       LabTestFailReason: NotDefined
       LabTestName: VerifyHyperlinkForIngestTab
       LabTestResult: PASS
       StartTime: Sun Sep 04 02:25:00 EST 51859
       TotalTime: 0`
This is what I see.. I am not sure why it says September

Comment: But u r getting it in human format right? if yes try to debug it, to see how its converting, because i can't check it.

Comment: Yes, thanks I am trying to figure out why it would not show the current date